# JSON data not accessible in a function outside designed to compare input data with json and then output

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The problem is that the json data is not be accessible in the function calculateInterest can't be made and there are no outputs.

This is the error that gets shown:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonResponse is not defined
>       at calculateInterest (script.js:36)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (script.js:29)

The point of this application is to output a yearly interest based on the input number. All of this is decided by json data that should compare the principal value with the json values and then decide the interest every year.

Here is a link to the project. https://github.com/BKwingwa/Interestcalculator/tree/master/InterestCalculator3

All fixes on similar problems uses jQuery and I'm only allowed to use pure JavaScript in this project as the intention from the teacher is to learn without any framework.

I've tried both an XMLHttpRequest based on w3schools and then tried to load the function inside the response as well as tried to use the XMLHttpRequest based on [this project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Even though I still can't seem get the json data inside the function while trying to type `calculateInterest(jsonResponse)` in both off these different xmlhttprequests.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnJson').addEventListener('click', loadJson);

    var principal = document.getElementById('principal').value;
}
```

// ----------------------------- Description of what the intention of this app is -----------------------------

// What should be fed out in the HTML is the interest depending on the number in the input. 
// JSON is the decider of what the yearly interest should be. The yearly interest is intended to be the output.

```
function loadJson()
{


    var requestURL = 'interest.json';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();


    request.onload = function()
    {
        var jsonResponse = request.response;
        calculateInterest(jsonResponse);
    }



    function calculateInterest()
    {
        if (principal >= jsonResponse[0].from && principal <= jsonResponse[0].up_to)
        {
         //  return document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = jsonResponse[0].interest;
         console.log(jsonResponse[0].interest);
        }

        else if (principal >= jsonResponse[1].from && principal <= jsonResponse[1].up_to)
        {
         //  return document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = jsonResponse[1].interest;
         console.log(jsonResponse[1].interest);
        }


    }

}

//var btn = document.getElementById('btnJSON').addEventListener('click', loadJson);
```

Expected results: 
What should be fed out in the HTML is the interest depending on the number in the input. 
JSON is the decider of what the yearly interest should be. The yearly interest is intended to be the output.

Currently the calculateInterest function is not working at all as it is not outputting the interest on the HTML in the paragraph element even though the JSON syntax seems to be correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Replace function definition 'function calculateInterest()' to 'function calculateInterest(jsonResponse)'.The problem is when calling the calculateInterest(jsonResponse), it has jsonResponse as a parameter. But the function definition is function calculateInterest().

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the fast reply Jay! Very kind of you. I've tried adding a parameter in the function below and it is my mistake forgetting to specify that. 

But what happens when that the parameter is added is that nothing happens at all, which is not the intention. I thought that one error to work with is better than having no errors when nothing is working so I removed it from jsonResponse as a parameter below. 

I unfortunately get nothing happening to happen when I add the parameter. Also want to thank Andrew for editing to make things more clear.

Comment: This program is now fixed and I want to provide information to other developers facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been fixed. This is a link to how the script looks when it's done. I've put comments so it's easier for understand for people, interested in learning. I've also commented out some old things so u can see some things that were replaced.

Link to the updated file on Github: https://github.com/BKwingwa/Interestcalculator/blob/master/updatedscript